# Sample tuples without replacement where each tuple contains unique numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

**Problem.** Given the set $\mathbf S = [1, \ldots, n] \subset \mathbb N$, generate $m$ random $k$-tuples, where

1. the numbers constituting each tuple are unique (i.e., drawn without replacement),
2. within each tuple, the number $i \in \mathbf S$ is drawn with a given probability $p_i$.
3. the ordering in each tuple doesn't matter (e.g., $(2, 3, 1)$ is considered the same as $(1, 2, 3))$ and
4. the tuples are unique (i.e., drawn without replacement).

**Example 1.** For $\mathbf S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$, $k = 3$ and $m = 4$, this would be a valid output:

$(3, 4, 1),\; (1, 2, 5),\; (5, 1, 3),\; (1, 2, 3)$,

given that $1$ was drawn with probability $p_1$, 2 was drawn with probability $p_2$ and so on.

**Example 2.** Given the assumptions in Example 1, this would be an invalid output:

$(3, 4, 1),\; (3, 4, 1),\; (5, 1, 3),\; (1, 2, 3)$,

since the first two tuples are the same.

**Note.** Hints in implementing that in C++ are also welcome.

Comment: As I interpret your question, the $p_i$ are fixed values, i.e. there exist $p_1,\ldots,p_n> 0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$ that are to specify the probability that $i\in\mathbf S$ is in a given tuple. However, assuming $k<n$, for any subset $T\subset\mathbf N$ with $|T|=k$ we have $\sum_{i\in T} p_i < 1$, which is not a valid probability distribution. Did you mean to normalize the probabilities by dividing by this sum (so that the probabilities sum to one)?

Comment: After an $i \in \mathbf S$ has been drawn and becomes part of a tuple, yes, the probabilities for the remaining elements in $\mathbf S$ have to be normalized to give a valid distribution. Just like the special case of uniform sampling: the probability of any $i$ is $1/n$, then after drawing the first $i$  they become $1/(n-1)$ for the rest and so on. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

In R, suppose you are generating 'pairs' $(k = 2)$ so that elements are chosen from among 1 through 6 $(m=6).$ Elements must be different, and numbers $1,2,3$ are $1/4$ as likely as numbers $4,5,6$ (among possibilities remaining). Then R code is `sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))`.
[At each choice, R normalizes the proportionality vector for remaining possible choices.]

```
set.seed(903)
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 5 2
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 2 5
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 4 6
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 5 4
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 6 4
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 3 5
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 4 6
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 4 6
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 5 4
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 6 3
sample(1:6, 2, p=c(1,1,1,4,4,4))
[1] 6 3
```

Depending on your answer to @Math1000's comment, an alternative method would be to sample *with* replacement (using argument `repl=T`), and to reject results where numbers chosen are not distinct, provided $m \ge k.$

Comment: 1. There are multiple pairs in the output that are repeated: (5, 4), (6, 3) and others, i.e., the solution is wrong.
2. This is not an algorithm, but a suggestion how to use R.